# Is something wrong with my zucchini plant?

Tags: diseases, pests, zucchini

I have three large zucchini plants in my garden, and all three have been producing nice fruits for a few weeks.  The last couple days, one of them has started to turn yellow and sickly:

[image]
[image]

I've never grown zucchini before, so I'm not sure if this is just the natural progression, and the plant's life is over... or if this is a sign of some damage or disease.  If it is the latter, can I nurse the plant back to health? Or should I destroy it so it doesn't infect the remaining healthy plants?

---

### EDIT

In response to @EdStaub's answer, here's a new photo of the base of the plant, at three magnifications:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look at the stem, down near the base.  Do you see some distinctive brown-orange sawdust-like material?  If so, that's called frass, and your plant is being destroyed by one or more squash vine borers.  The [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squash_vine_borer) is really good, and shows pictures (at the bottom) of what to look for.

We've tried killing the grubs in the stem, with a hatpin and other things, with partial success.

Some varieties of squash have some resistance to borers.  I don't know about zucchini, though.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have updated my question with a new photo.  The base looks horrible... with brown-orange material. I think you diagnosed it.  Thanks.

Comment: Upon closer inspection, it looks like all of my zucchini plants are infested, just the one pictured is the worst off.  I found one fruit with worms crawling out of it, too.  *sigh* I'll probably rip most of it out.

Comment: Don't rip them out quite yet! I just dealt with the same exact problem. I ended up ripping out a few plants, but I think I managed to save some as well. For plants that don't look like a total loss, you can look for possible entry points on the stems. Make a lengthwise slit a few inches above the highest visible sign of damage. You'll often end up getting the vine borer using this method. Start with the plants that look like a total loss, so you can get some practice on making the cuts. Then when you move on to the healthier-but-still-infected plants, you have a better chance of saving them.

Comment: Also, if your other squash is under attack as well, you can bury portions of the vine to encourage rooting. Then a vine-borer attacking the base of your plant won't kill the entire plant. bstpierre gave me a pretty good answer on my related question: http://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/4634/6

Comment: @Flimzy, see Doresoom's comments here - I agree - we've gotten squash from plants where only a small portion of the stem remained.

Comment: @Doresoom: Thanks for the advice. That's exactly what I did this morning.  Two plants were practically dead, so I pulled them up, and burned the stem portions to kill any larvae.  Two other plants had obvious infestations, but still looked relatively healthy.  I cut into the stems, and killed 3-4 worms in each one.  I then buried the stem up a ways with fresh soil, and a separate part of the vine as well.

Comment: I also planted my last 2 zucchini seeds from this year's seed packet in place of one of the uprooted plants... I don't know if it'll bear any fruit this season, but 2 seeds weren't worth saving for next year anyway :)