# Does it look like a vine borer caused this damage to my zucchini?

Tags: vegetables, diagnosis, plant-health, zucchini

After reading the [accepted answer](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/a/4718/2575) on the question "[Is something wrong with my zucchini plant?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/4716/2575)", I've come to the conclusion that it is in fact a vine borer which has invaded my zucchini. Based on the following pictures, does this seem like the correct conclusion?

Is it too late to save this plant?

*Click photo for full size*
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks quite bad and I would say it will continue to spread and eventually kill your plant.
There are sprays which you can buy, but it looks like it may be too far gone.

Rather than nothing, I would suggest as a last resort, try cutting as much of the affected plant back as possible and place soil around any new roots shooting off from the unaffected areas.

It's a long shot, but worth a try.

Good Luck!

Comment: Yes, I figured I would try that today. My fault for not being more vigilant. Thanks for the advice!